# VS2013 Find in Files Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013 and I use the Find in Files option to search for text in my solution.  The Find result window correctly lists all the locations the text was found.

However when I press F8 to step through all the locations VS2013 found the text the file isn't opened.  Instead it shows the following text on the bottom of the screen "The system can not find the file specified".

I've found that if the file is already open in VS2013 then it can show the next location that the text was found.  Also if I double click on a line in the Find Results window then VS2013 correctly opens the file.

So how can VS2013 find the text I'm looking for and be unable to find the file specified?

It doesn't matter if I hit F8 on the keyboard, or the "Go to Next Location" button with my mouse, neither will open the file.

Comment: Have you checked your keyboard shortcut mappings (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/da5kh0wa.aspx for how to do this)? You haven't somehow ended up with F8 mapped to something other than the default?

Comment: Can't repro. In fact, I didn't know about `F8` until I show this question. It does move to the next location and opens the file if it's closed. Are you using an add-in that replaces the `F8` shortcut?

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report problems like this.